# A single website is denying selenium only with VPN

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to [this](https://www.sothebys.com) website with selenium over a VPN, but am unsuccessful.

The weird thing is that this website does load in a normal browser with the same VPN connection. Even weirder is the fact that I have tried some 100 other websites over the VPN with selenium and all of them work! Crazy.

The specific error message when trying to connect is:
The connection has timed out, the server is taking too long to respond. This is the second day in a row I try with the same result. I have tried a few other VPN's as well but with no success. Without VPN I can access the website with selenium, so somehow the combination of selenium and the VPN is turning out problematic for just this 1 website.

The VPN used is OpenVPN 2.4.4 on linux which was setup with OpenSSL 1.1.1, tcp443.

I tried to set the VPN directly in Selenium as well with no success. If someone has any clue on why this might be happening it would greatly help me. Thanks.

Comment: So there are some sites that don't like to be scraped or automated and servers block requests. If the website has an API you should use it. Please be careful if you are offering a service on your website to automatically do something you can get into trouble for not following user policy sometimes even legal charges.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I was just wondering how it can be the case that a website is able to detect VPN only when using selenium. Both separately don't get detected.

Comment: For future reference, I have also tried requests library with many types of headers without success. I finally was able to reach the page with VPN by using Selenium in a Chrome browser instead of Firefox which I was using first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware on the scraping policies published by websites, and adhere to them accordingly. The robot.txt file states clearly that some pages can be crawled with proper crawl-delay.

The core of my question was how it can be the case that a website is able to detect VPN only when using selenium. Both separately did not get detected.

I have tried to access this web page over VPN with the requests library and many types of headers but remained unsuccessful. In the end I was successful by launching Selenium with Chrome driver instead of Firefox. This allowed me to access the site over VPN:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service('/mnt/wwn-0x5002538e00000000/chromedriver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get('http://www.url....');
```